# OpenApi versioning by header in Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, version-control, openapi

I am using Spring Boot to run my service. Now I want to be able to define different versions of my api and separate them by some header. My current approach is to design specification first and then use openapi generator to get delegates.

For example, I have a spec file similar to this

```
openapi: 3.0.2
paths:
  /api/stuff:
    get:
      operationId: method
      parameters:
        - in: header
          name: version
          type: integer
      responses:
        '200':
          $ref: '#/components/responses/DtoV1'
```

How can I say that for version 2 I will return `DtoV2`?
And how will Spring handle those Controllers and Delegates?